# Best way to pass a query result to another page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, performance

Quick question:

I have a page that makes an AJAX call to my SQL server and receives an XML response. I parse the XML and display the relevant data in a table.

I have a button on the page that is used to display the table data in a simple line graph on a new page. Currently, I just re-query the database and to re-get the data and create a new array object of that data for my graph.

The GET can take up to 2.5 seconds, with the final graph time to render being about 8-9 seconds. I am investigating any alternatives to re-GET'ting the data.

So far I have:

- localStorage (HTML5)
- php pass me the data instead of querying the DB
- jquery plugin (DOMCache)

Any thoughts on this or best practices??

thanks for any input!

Comment: You're using local storage. I suppose you wish the data to be reused for a long time, then? I'm thinking days here. Because if it's short lived, using the local storage is cluttering the user's machine storage. For short lived stuff, I'd rather use the user session, server side. Assign a GUID for a key if the user may have many of these tables being displayed in different tabs and have the data die out after some fixed amount of time.

Comment: you can build and json object using javascript then stringify the object and pass it over POST variable to you server, then in the new page you can render decode the javascript object and show the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do best to just make sure the response is cached in your users' browsers.  There are a variety of ways to make this happen (variant upon the framework your server is running, browsers that your clients are using, etc etc), but the long story short is that relying upon caching will alleviate you from having to jump through performance hoops by making  modifications to your codebase.

IE8+ is actually a kingpin in this area (much as I hate to admit it).  Its aggressive caching of ajax responses is usually a serious pain in the arse, but in this case would prove valuable to your scenario.

**Edit -** 
You mentioned SQL Server, so I'm making the assumption that you're running through an ASP.NET middle tier.  If that's the case, [here's an interesting article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19394/Client-side-caching-for-script-methods-access-in-A) on caching ajax requests on the server *and* the client with the .NET framework.